# Crashed: Crashed: com.apple.main-thread EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000010063e990

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm trying to get the user interface style but I'm getting this random issue running on iOS15 devices. I can't fix it because while I'm testing the app, the crash doesn't appear:

**Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT**

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Resultados                     0x10063e990 specialized static Device.getCurrentAppareance() + 196 (Device.swift:196)
1  Resultados                     0x100722510 closure #1 in UIImageView.setImage(url:type:placeholder:) + 193 (UIImageViewExtensions.swift:193)
2  Resultados                     0x100710620 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 4311713312 (<compiler-generated>:4311713312)
3  libdispatch.dylib              0x1826852ec _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x1826862f0 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1826676a4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$armv81 + 904
6  CoreFoundation                 0x1829757f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
7  CoreFoundation                 0x1829330f8 __CFRunLoopRun + 2528
8  CoreFoundation                 0x182945d8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
9  GraphicsServices               0x19ca529a0 GSEventRunModal + 160
10 UIKitCore                      0x18517b018 -[UIApplication _run] + 1080
11 UIKitCore                      0x184f0f29c UIApplicationMain + 2060
12 Resultados                     0x1004128a4 main + 18 (main.m:18)
13 ???                            0x101958190 (Missing)
```

Here's the code:

```
func setImage(url: String?, type: EntityContent, placeholder: String?){
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
        // Get system appareance
        let appareance = Device.getCurrentAppareance()
        
        switch(type, appareance){
            
            // Team
            case (.team, .light):
            self.setImage(url: url, placeholder: TeamNoPhoto.small)
            break
                
            case (.team, .dark):
            self.setRoundedImage(url: url, placeholder: TeamNoPhoto.small)
            break
            
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

```
static func getCurrentAppareance() -> UIStyle {
    
    var uistyle : UIStyle = .light
    
    // Check for dark mode
    if #available(iOS 13, *){
        
        let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController!
        
        if viewController.traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            uistyle = .dark
        }
        
    }
    
    return uistyle
    
}
```

In the previous versions of iOS, everything is working well but not in iOS15 and I don't know why. The app crashes when the case (.team, .light) is evaluated. Also fails when *getCurrentAppareance* returns the value of uistyle var.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Device.swift:196` - which line is that?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear in my question. Is "return uistyle".

Comment: That's really, really, really strange :) Crashes usually occur when accessing no longer valid data, or when executing something not permitted. Haven't yet seen a crash on a `return` statement.

Comment: The crash is related with the main thread but I can't find the reason. But I don't know why the report shows the crash in that line :)

Comment: Maybe the code you shipped had something else al tine 196?

Comment: That's the end of the file. I'm struggling with this crash, I've tested the app in some devices, but I can't reproduce it. It's not related with a specific iPhone model, is totally random, so it may be due to a memory problem.

Comment: Did you fix this? @fdlr